# How to run a C# method from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I want to be able to run the following:

```
public static string SafeTrim(string s) => s == null ? null : s.Trim();
```

By doing something like:

```
update MyTable set MyString = SafeTrim(MyString)
```

in the database. Is this possible?

Comment: `LTRIM(RTRIM(NULL))` is still `NULL`.  I don't see the point of using such a method in `SQL`.

Comment: Have a look at MSDN docs about CLR functions, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Why not write a sql udf? But yes you can write dlls that can be imported into sql so long as the appropriate clr options are on (if I remember correctly) Google should help

Comment: @McNets Thanks, add that as an answer and I shall accept it. I did not know the name CLR to Google.

Comment: Why not just create a stored procedure and do the exact same thing, but in sql ?

Comment: @BernardWalters C# is better at string manipulation than SQL. This was just a simple example, I want to do more complex stuff later.

Comment: @Siyual see above comment. Also LTRIM and RTRIM do not trim newlines afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a C# code on SQL Server you must set up a CLR User Defined Function.

Have a look at MSDN Docs.

[How to: Create and Run a SQL Server User-Defined Function by using Common Language Run-time Integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Create a SQL user-defined function by adding a User-Defined Function to a SQL Server Common Language Run-time (SQL CLR) database project. After successful deployment, the user-defined function can be called and executed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like the page is outdated. In step 3 on the linked page(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84b1se47(v=vs.100).aspx) it says to create a "Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project" but I don't seem to have that template on VS 2015. Do you know what I should use instead?

Comment: Let me check my current VS versions.

Comment: No, but using a SQL Database project, it let me add a new item as SQL CLR C# User defined function, Stored procedure, trigger, etc...

Comment: Yes, but then in the other linked article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dahcx0ww(v=vs.100).aspx) it says to right click the project and go to "Deploy", which doesn't exist for an SQL Database project.

Comment: Right click solution -> Deploy solution

Comment: If not you can install dll from sql, let me search the article.

Comment: that sounds more like what I want. Just export a dll of all my methods and stick it in a folder on my database.

Comment: https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/manually-deploying-a-clr-stored-procedure/   https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009918/Installing-a-CLR-Stored-Procedure-on-SQL-Server.